# How to setup routing / NAT / Remote network for VPN in pfSense?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, pfsense, static-routes

I have a gateway machine—running under [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org)—and it has `VPN` connection to private network in range `10.0.0.0/8`.

I have standalone OpenVPN program, which allows me to connect to this net successfully. Now I would like to setup the same access on pfSense and allow all computers on my LAN to access that private net.

I have the following config for standalone

[image]

When I am connecting to this VPN with standalone, it is asking me a name and password. I put this name password pair into `/etc/vpnpassword` file on `pfSense` filesystem.

Next I tried to reproduce the config on pfSense web interface:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**BEGINNING**

First I have added static route on `pfSense` saying, that all traffic to this network should go via this `VPN` interface. And if I ping some of the `10.0.0.0/8` addresses in the range from the `pfSense` shell it works well.

But if I ping the address from some other machine from my LAN, it goes trough "default" gateway of `pfSense`.

Why and how to fix?

**UPDATE**

I have the following VPN entry:

[image]

I have added interface here manually and attached it to `ovpnc1` logical name taken from `OpenVPN` logs

[image]

I was unable to config `DHCP` for `VPN` -- it was causing errors. But it obtains `IP` somehow.

Now I have the following gateways:

[image]

I don't understand, where `OVPNC1_VPNV6` came from.

Finally I have the following static routes:

[image]

This page has a warning below:

> Note: Do not enter static routes for networks assigned on any
>   interface of this firewall. Static routes are only used for networks
>   reachable via a different router, and not reachable via your default
>   gateway.

which implies that my routes are unneeded.

But why isn't it working then?

**UPDATE 2**

Now I have removed manually created interface from `Interfaces` tab. This caused disappearance of `OpenVPN` from some places like routing. But it remained on pages like `Firewall` or `NAT`.

Probably this is an expected way to config.

Unfortunately, it didn't give any results: VPN addresses can be pinged from pfSense shell but can't be pinged from LAN computers.

**UPDATE 3**

I found a place where to put remote LAN addresses -- it was on OpenVPN setup page:

[image]

It helped me, but partially. Now I can ping `10.72.8.1`, but can't ping `10.75.6.33`. I was unable to ping former address before last setting made.

**UPDATE 4**

The following setting also do not help

[image]

Comment: Address 10.72.8.1 and similar. Why is it expected behavior? I was suspecting this, but can't understand. If router was told that some address is reachable via some interface, then why isn't it route accordingly? Please explain.